# Generic method that will return different types according to input parameter

Tags: c#, generics

In my project in a lot of places I am processing a csv file. The files contain different data - some contain ingredients, some employees, some books, etc.

So, I have this situation:

- csv file 1 contains this structure: bookId;bookName;bookAuthor;...
- csv file 2 contains: ingredientId;ingredientAmount;price;name;...
- csv file 3 contains: employeeId;employeeContractId;name;...

I want to create a generic method that as input parameters will have the path of the file, rules and what to return.

The rules will be a list of key value pairs that will tell which index of the row contains which property of db. So, for csv file 1, the rules list will be something like this:

```
<Enum.bookId, 0> --in each row, the string with index 0 in the string after splitting by ";", has the id of the book
<Enum.bookName, 1>
<Enum.bookAuthor, 2>
```

What bugs me is that this method should somehow return different object for each of the 3 csv files mentioned above. So for file 1 I have a table in db called Book, so the generic method should return a list of books. For csv file 2 it should return a list of ingredients, etc. This method will be called from different classes, so I was thinking it should have an input parameter that somehow tells it what it should return. Or maybe has an input parameter T. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the type `T` as part of the generic method's declaration, and pass the correct type when calling it.

For example declare it like this:

```
public List<T> ParseFile<T>(string filePath)
{
    ...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var books = ParseFile<Book>("path of books.csv");
```

However once you realise that you have to pass the type as a type parameter, you might also realise that it doesn't help much making the method generic like that.

You might as well be explicit:

```
public List<Book> ParseBookFile(string filePath)
{
    ...
}
```

If you try to return `object` from your parser, you still end up having to cast that to the correct type at some point, so it doesn't really gain you much.